# Zen Coding updated emacs mode

Tags: emacs, emmet

It seems that the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/rooney/zencoding) for Zen Coding in emacs is not actively maintained (last commit was a year ago), and there are some features missing, e.g. the `html:5` "tag".

I couldn't find any other sources for the emacs mode. Does anyone know if there exists an updated version?

The Zen Coding google group links to EmacsWiki which in turn links to the above mentioned GitHub repo.

Comment: I don't know if the chances are good to get support, but I decided that asking for it can't hurt: so here is the issue at the github repo: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/issues/215

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [forked](https://github.com/smihica/emmet) zencoding-mode and added some new features support, e.g. [html:5](https://github.com/smihica/zencoding#aliases) tag, [CSS abbreviations](https://github.com/smihica/zencoding#css-abbreviations).
And you can define more by editing conf/snippets.json and recompiling.

Please try it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Zen Coding is now [Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/). Sadly, Emacs isn't one of their supported editors.

[This GitHub repo](https://github.com/rooney/zencoding) is probably the canonical zencoding implementation, although [this fork](https://github.com/smihica/zencoding) has [support for HTML 5](https://github.com/smihica/zencoding/commit/05b9826295d902ed00d0971437e5d5de76fb7d9b).

Comment: Are you sure there is an Emacs implementation?

Comment: that explains it, but as @L42y hints, I don't see an emacs mode anywhere?

Comment: Updated answer -- Emmet doesn't provide a first-party Emacs implementation. Looks like people are forking the existing zencoding mode with updates to keep up with Emmet.

Answer (score -1):

the author had commit the new version,and this fork has supported html snippets... i recommand it for you

---

i had install [this fork](https://github.com/smihica/zencoding), but it doesn't work for many new tags like html:5,input:i...anynoe encounted this problem? i sent a email to the author,but i have not received any answers till now.